# C++ Ref Count Changes While Destructing Object

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined, shared, ref

I've got a private ref count inside the class SharedObject. SharedObject is a base class for other classes, for example Window. Window is the base class of Editor.

When the ref count reaches 0, because of calling SharedObject::Release(), the SharedObject deletes itself. First we get to the Editor destructor, which shows that the this pointer contains m_refs == 0, but when we get to the Window destructor it is suddenly 1, and when we reach the SharedObject destructor, it is still 1.

I put a breakpoint on the SharedObject::IncRef() method, and it was never called while this happened.

What the?

Comment: Can you provide more code and more context?  From your description alone it's virtually impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Make sure IncRef is not inlined, that disables breakpoints.

Comment: The IncRef is not inlined, the breakpoint works. But the function doesn't break when the Editor is destructing so I suppose it isn't called.

Comment: More code and context.. not sure what to give exactly. It is quite a lot of code for a game engine. I prefer to know possibilities of what might be wrong. Perhaps heap corruption?

Answer (score 2):

Build with optimizations off, and set a memory breakpoint on your m_refs.

Comment: How do I set a breakpoint on the m_ref member variable? All optimizations are off but the breakpoint jumps to the nearest function below when I breakpoint the memeber.
The member is private, and I have public IncRef() and Release() functions, but like I said the breakpointing indicates these functions are subverted somehow.

Comment: Which debugger are you using?  In windbg, the ba command (Break on Access) will get what you want.  In Visual Studio, it's called a Data Breakpoint:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know, I will definitely try this! But it seems my program has some heap corruption problems (again, sigh), and this might be causing various problems. AppVerifier is finding some problems already.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have memory leak somewhere, maybe even long before this destruction occurs. I use Alleyoop to find leaks. Can help, won't hurt to have that out of the way.

Do you use multiple threads? Maybe it's due to some raw pointer somewhere being grabbed by other thread during destruction.

On a side note, I recommend using boost::intrusive_ptr - very convinient pattern for handling addrefs and releases in shared objects that helps to be consequent with it, but this probably won't solve your problem unless you have a real mess in your code ;)

Comment: I used the wrong expression. I meant any kind of memory corruption. Maybe there's some way your object has already been destroyed (it's possible if you use raw pointers somewhere) and now you're getting random effects. Maybe there's a cast to wrong struct somewhere and you're writing over fields that you don't want to. Maybe you're using a function that expects null-terminated string (ex. sscanf, strlen) on a buffer without null. Posibilities are endless and all generate random effects.